# Vue console error Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.... is undefined on value with is defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have an issue with I don't understand:

simply I going to display some data from API its all works perfectly but I getting an error that `personnel.departmentID` is `undefined`, and my vue-debug tool not working.

I'm getting it only when I assign anything from `departmentID` while for the rest like firstName, lastName, etc.

The strange thing that data for `departmentID.name` etc. it's displaying properly but it throws the following error.

in my console I getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.personnel.departmentID is undefined
    render edit_personnel.vue:64
    renderComponentRoot runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:846
    componentEffect runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4280
    reactiveEffect reactivity.esm-bundler.js:42
    effect reactivity.esm-bundler.js:17
    setupRenderEffect runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4263
    mountComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4222
    processComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4182
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3791
    render runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4883
    mount runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3077
    mount runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1259
    js personnel_edit.js:4
    Webpack 7
```

Value its displayed properly

[input displayed with correct data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7fx4.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbXLU.png)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="personnel.departmentID.name" :key="personnel.departmentID.name" />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>

export default {
  name: "edit_personnel",
  data: () => ({
    personnel: [],
    departments: [],
    location: [],
    loaded: false,
  }),
  async created() {
    await fetch(window.currentUserId)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.personnel = data;
          this.loaded = true;
        });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where's the code with `_ctx.personnel.departmentID`?

Comment: What is the response JSON you get back from the fetch() call? you have personnel defined as an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `personnel` data is an `async` action, you should have a `v-if` directive on your `input` to prevent it from erroring on load.

Fix your data to be an object instead of an array,

```
personnel: {}
```

And your template should change to,

```
    <input
      v-if="personnel.departmentID"
      type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      v-model="personnel.departmentID.name" 
      :key="personnel.departmentID.name" />
  </form>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to init the `personnel` property like :

```
      data: () => ({
        personnel: {
                  departmentID:{name:'' }
                },
        departments: [],
        location: [],
        loaded: false,
      }),
      async c
```

Since `departmentID` is undefined at the first rendering.